# SQL Sum of numbers from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split

I have a string like this:)

`"<"FOSTIMON 75 M.J.>|4|4|4|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3||||||||||||||||||||||||||||"`

I need the sum of the numbers (4+4+4+3+...+3), expected result = 39

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  You might also want to explain why these numbers are in a string rather than in separate columns.

Comment: I use MS SQL. The numbers are saved from another sw, I need only a checksum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Assuming the first part of the string upto the first "|" can be ignored
Not sure what version of SQL you're using but if its less than SQL2016 then use this [string splitter](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(50) = '<"FOSTIMON 75 M.J.>|4|4|4|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3||||||||||||||||||||||||||||'

SELECT 
     SUM(CONVERT(INT, S.[Value]))
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@s, '|') S
WHERE S.RN >= 2 AND S.RN <= 13
```

If you're on SQL2012 + then you can utilise [TRY_PARSE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and get rid of the WHERE clause altogether

```
SELECT 
     SUM(   
            CASE
                WHEN TRY_PARSE(S.[Value] AS INT) IS NOT NULL
                THEN CONVERT(INT, S.[Value])
                ELSE 0
            END
            --CONVERT(INT, S.[Value])
        )
FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@s, '|') S
```

If you're using SQL2016 + then use the inbuilt function, [String_Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
SELECT 
        SUM(    
            CASE
                WHEN TRY_PARSE(S.[Value] AS INT) IS NOT NULL
                THEN CONVERT(INT, S.[Value])
                ELSE 0
            END
        )
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@s, '|') S
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot the specify the sql version 2010. This solution doesn't work on this version.

Comment: @Hans33 The first one I posted should Not the last two.

Comment: Invalid object name 'dbo.DelimitedSplit8K'.

Comment: I linked to the article that contains the function in the answer

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL QUESTION BEFORE EDITING.

Most databases support executing some form of prepared statement.  In your case, probably the simplest method is to construct a SQL statement and then execute it dynamically.

The syntax for this varies dramatically from database to database.  Out of randomness, I'm choosing SQL Server, but the functionality (although not the syntax) is available in almost any database:

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) = '|4|4|4|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3|3||||||||||||||||||||||||||||';

set @str = 'select ' + replace(@str, '|', '+') + ' + 0';

exec sp_executesql @str;
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/YOMXPB51449) is a rextester for this particular version.

Note that this works because `+` is a unary (numeric) operator, analogous to `-` but it does not change the sign.

Comment: Nice, but the OP has updated the question with a revised string